# Error when converting a web.config to .htaccess in rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config

I'm migrating a server, it was all php but it was on a windows server (don't know why, but it is what it is :P)

```
  <rule name="category2" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^categoryi/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+)" ignoreCase="false" />      
     <action type="Rewrite" url="listbycategory.php?id={R:1}&amp;pagenumber={R:2}" />" />
  </rule>
```

I tried with:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^categoryi/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+)/?$ listbycategory.php?id=$1&amp;nroPagina=$2
```

But the world explodes, any clues on what i'm making a mess?

Comment: you close your action tag twice, is that a typo?

Comment: if in webconfig in action then yes, if not i'm not seeing it

Comment: What do you mean with "the world explodes"?

Comment: hehe :P "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the space in your rewrite rule, so change your rewrite rule line into:

```
RewriteRule ^categoryi/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\ -]+)/?$ listbycategory.php?id=$1&amp;nroPagina=$2
```

Note the \ before the space.

By the way, is it on purpose that you changed the pagenumber variable into nroPagina?